# How do I control the volume of current active media player?

Tags: windows, automation, media

My goal is to control the volume of the current media playing application on Windows 11 instead of the system wide volume. This should be done from a small console programm.
This program will then be called using programmable keys on my keyboard.

I already know of the "[System Media Transport Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/integrate-with-systemmediatransportcontrols?source=recommendations)" API in the .NET Framework to play/pause, skip, get track/artist information but it doesn't seem to be possible to control the volume using SMTC.

I'm open to other languages than C# if there's a possibility to accomplish my goal but since it's for Windows, I expect a solution to be using the .NET Framework.

Under Linux, this is possible using dbus/MPRIS. I hope there's a solution for Windows.

**Is there a way to control the volume of the current active media player?**